# How to disable scrolling inside datagrid in wpf c#

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have done  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" because i dont want the content inside datagrid to be viewed which crosses the assigned height. I am not able to see scroll bar after giving the above statement.but i still can scroll down and see the rows.Can someone tell me how do i disable scrolling all together?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Once you've disabled the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` for your DatGrid, you need to disable the ScrollViewer's scroll functionality like this:

`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`

But when you do his make sure that you have already defined a standard height for your entire DataGrid and your DataGrid rows such that the user can see all the rows you want them to see, otherwise the chopped off rows will not be displayed and the user can not scroll down to see them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

The correct approach would be to disable the Hit target

```
DataGrid.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't solve the problem if you're hoping to actually be able to click within the data grid (just to ignore the mouse scroll inside it)

Comment: It also disables clicking on the rows

Answer (score 3):

Allow DataGrid to show all it's content (so it needn't scroll bar):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" />
</Grid>
```

You can than put the result in any place. It'll cut down it's size to the owner's dimensions

Comment: this does not solve the problem, especially if the data grid has many rows

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution did not work for me since I needed row selection.
I solved all my issues by disabling datagrid panning (for mouse dragging) and handling key down events (for keyboard).
In datagrid XAML:

```
ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None"
```

And:

```
PreviewKeyDown="OnDatagridPreviewKeyDown"
```

In code behind:

```
private void OnDatagridPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Left)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

HTH.

Edit: My answer applies to columns but everything is similar for rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an answer that applied to columns. On occasion, you may find that the Datagrid will scroll to extra columns that you would prefer remain invisible, especially if the height is specifically adjusted so that any additional columns are invisible. I simply attached a Loaded handler to the Datagrid and set all of the additional columns to a width of 0 and made them hidden.